# Is there a way to have Entity property in Symfony, which holds combination of properties of same Entity?

Tags: php, entity-framework, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

In my Symfony 4 project I have a `Entity Class` `Users` with properties `firstName` and `familyName` and i would like to add something like `fullName` which would be concatenation of those two, but without adding column into DB. I need it for example for show in front-end and filter in tables. But sometimes is separation also needed.

Class definition:

```
/**
 * Users
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Users
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="FIRST_NAME", type="string", length=25, nullable=false)
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="FAMILY_NAME", type="string", length=25, nullable=false)
     */
    private $familyName;

  // Other properties and getters + setters
}
```

When i add just property `fullName` with getters and setters:

```
private $fullName;

public function getFullName():?string
{
    return $this->getFamilyName().', '.$this->getFirstName();
}

public function setFullName(string $fullName): self{
    return $this;
}
```

and use it in `QueryBuilder` as

```
createQueryBuilder()->select('u.fullName')->from('App\Entity\Users','u')->where('u.id = ?')...
```

then I got this Error:

```
'fullName FROM': Error: Class App\Entity\Users has no field or association named fullName
```

Is there an easy way, how to say to Doctrine, that this property goes not from DB but exist as a "virtual column"? I know, that i can use DQL function `Concat` etc., but i need this. And from my perspective is this a bit nicer.

Comment: Is concatening in the query out of the question ? such as ->select('CONCAT(user.firstname, \' \', user.lastname) AS full_name')

Comment: Why do you need it in Doctrine? With just the getter method - without the additional property - you can use it wherever you need it in php / twig. To filter in Doctrine, you would need 2 separate `andWhere()` clauses.

Comment: @DylanKas yes, this is out of the question.

Comment: @jeroen I know that, but i can not use it in queryBuilder and that is what i need.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function getFullName(): string
{
    return \implode(', ', \array_filter([$this->getFamilyName(), $this->getFirstName()]));
}
```

That's all you need to retrieve fullName from Entity.

But since you don't have it in mapping or a real column in table you should use DQL expression like this:

```
createQueryBuilder()->select("CONCAT(u.familyName, ', ', u.firstName)")->from('App\Entity\Users','u')->where('u.id = ?')
```